# standard dropdown arrow visible in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, css

i got the follow custom dropdown

[image]

which works like a charm in chrome but in firefox i get this:

[image]

is there any possibility to hide that dropdown arrow in firefox?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with mobile IE on Windows Phone 7.5.  -ms-appearance doesn't work and it looks hideous.

Comment: see solution, i managed to get it to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i found out that it is not possible to hide it in every browser as its not defined by the standard, instead i used this awesome approach:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could try to add these lines in your dropdown menu css:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```